# using JOIN and subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select, join

I posted a question about 2 weeks ago about 'one to many' relation between SQL tables. Now I have a bit of a different scenario. Basically, there are two tables - coffee_users and coffee_product_registrations. The latter is connected to coffee_users table with 'uid' column. So basically coffee_users.uid = coffee_product_registrations.uid

A single user can have multiple products registered.

What I want to do is to display some product information (from coffee_product_registrations) along with some user information (from coffee_users), BUT retrieve only those rows that have more than 1 product registrations.

So to simplify, here are the steps I need to take:

1. Join two tables
2. Select users that have multiple products registered
3. Display all their products along with their names and stuff

My current SQL query looks like this:

```
SELECT c.uid, c.name, cpr.model 
FROM coffee_users c 
JOIN coffee_product_registrations cpr on c.uid = cpr.uid
GROUP BY c.uid 
HAVING COUNT(cpr.uid) > 1
```

This joins the two tables on 'uid' column but displays only 1 row for each user. It selects just users that have multiple products registered.

Now I need to take these IDs and select ALL the products from coffee_product_registrations based on them.

I cannot figure out how to put this in one query.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `cpr.*, c.*` with columns which you want to extract feom the query

Try this:

```
SELECT cpr.*, c.*
FROM coffee_product_registrations cpr 
INNER JOIN coffee_users c ON c.uid = cpr.uid
INNER JOIN (SELECT cpr.uid 
            FROM coffee_product_registrations cpr 
            GROUP BY cpr.uid 
            HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cpr.productId) > 1
           ) AS A ON c.uid = A.uid;
```

Comment: Returns an empty result. So should I have 2 inner joins then? Can I not have one?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59078 is the sqlfiddle. I've created 2 usernames - user1 and user2. user1 has 2 products registered under coffee_product_registrations and user2 has only 1. So the query should select all the products of user1 and display both products in addition to the email and ID of user1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by table format but what I'm trying to achieve is this: Display all products of users who have more than 1 product registered and each product should have the user's email and ID alongside.

Comment: One user can have as many products registered as they want. I want to select only those users that have more than 1 product registered and then I want to display product details for each product that these selected users have.